# Simple example of function() use(){} not working

Tags: php

when running in [writecodeonline](http://www.writephponline.com/) i get

> syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting '{' on line 4

```
$x = "Hi guys";


function foo() use($x) {

 echo $x; 
}

foo();
```

Comment: isn't `use` for anonymous functions?

Comment: Yes @lascort, yes it is :-)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be mistaken but I've seen `use` on anonymous functions only. Try something like this

```
$x = "Hi guys";

$theFunction = function () use ($x) {
  echo $x;
};

$theFunction();
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
$x = "Hi guys";
$foo= function () use ($x ) {
    echo $x;
};
$foo();
```

[Read up on Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)